# jHipster - How to add new User Roles

Tags: java, spring-security, jhipster

Trying to add a new role (ROLE_MANAGERS) on a `JHipster 2.27.2` generated project. I can see the tables that need to be updated (role, authority and role_authority mapping).

How can I add the new role?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment in JHipster the roles/authorities are not exposed over a restful resource.

So there are 2 options for you to proceed:

1. you find a file src/main/resources/config/liquibase/authorites.csv and add all the roles you need. They will be generated as soon as liquibase migrates your database
2. implement some RestController for managing them

Answer (score 0):

Liquidbase will not automatically update roles you need to insert each note into the JHI_AUTHORITY table.

and that's not enough because some js scripts has hardcoded authority list you should update.

here a good link that sumarizes steps to update authority role list:
http://techknowblogs.blogspot.fr/2016/12/adding-new-role-in-jhipster.html